# PHP MySQL HTML Newsticker

Tags: php, mysql, marquee, news-ticker

i've the following problem and I don't know how I can fix this right now.

This is my current code

```
<?php   
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mkeey");  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_news ORDER BY id LIMIT 5";  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
?>  
<html>  
<head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <title>Newsticker Test</title>   
    <link href="content/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
</head>  
    <body>   
        <div class="marquee">
            <div>
                <?php  
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                    {  
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                        {  
                            $title = $row['news_title'];
                            $message = $row['news_text'];
                            echo '<span><b>['.$title.']</b> : '.$message.'</span>';
                        }  

                    }  
                ?>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>  
</html>
```

CSS

```
body { margin: 20px; }

.marquee {
  height: 55px;
  width: 50%;

  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee div {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 30px;

  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;

  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee span {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% { left: 0; }
  100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

The following problem, when I do the whole thing, the variables are constantly overwritten at the end of the border. This means that News1 is only visible and then News2 is briefly visible on the far left. How do I fix this problem?

So anyone who could help would be nice, thank you.

Comment: Side note: `<marquee>` is old and deprecated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you have a better solution, I'm happy to learn something new. Funky

Comment: Do you have some CSS that makes your `<p>` tags to be rendered inline? If you want the title and the text on the same line, you need to remove the `<br>` (which only purpose is to add a line break)

Comment: yes there is some CSS that makes my <p> tags rendered inline.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do it's job correctly. Please post all relevant code (like the CSS for the news ticker). It also looks like your marquee is inside some container? It's hard to see what's going on without seeing more context. However, as @FunkFortyNiner mentioned, the marquee tag is deprecated and there are other ways to do it. If you google "create news ticker", there are many articles/tutorials and I'm sure, ready libraries that you can use.

Comment: I edited my first post. Yes this is right but this is the easier way to google and just use. I'm ready to learn the language not just "copy & paste" :)

Comment: Tickers solve a UI problem where you have limited space to display information, and lots of people are sharing the display so it can't be interactive. On the web, you do not have those limitation. People can scroll at their own pace. The drawbacks (scrolling speed is too fast or too slow for a given user, and the problem of waiting for the start to come about) don't exist on the web. Consequently a ticket is a *terrible* UI choice for the WWW. Don't do this.

Comment: I've now changed my code again and now it's working how it should but now there is a other problem, it just gives me only the last row. First row NEWS1 and second row NEWS2 here again a screenshot : https://prnt.sc/tjnvyo
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your `echo` is outside the loop. That's why only the last entry is printed.
Put the `echo` into the loop and it'll fix the issue.

```
<?php  
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
{  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
    {  
    $title = $row['news_title'];
    $message = $row['news_text'];
    echo '<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();"><b>['.$title.']</b> : '.$message.'</marquee>';
    }  
}  
?>
```

Note: I don't want to start a flame about `<marquee>` being non-standard. Just be aware of that. Please consider using standard HTML elements or a combination of them: `a`, `p`, `div`, ...
Note that you can create marquee effect using pure standard HTML and CSS. Just search for "css only marquee".